# Event Emitter Memory Leak

Tags: node.js, http, memory-leaks, eventemitter

I've read a bunch on this topic, but still don't understand the issue with my code (or the problem with my logic/understanding of what's actually going on). Can someone please explain what I'm missing?

Basically, I've narrowed this problem down to when I run the following HTTP GET request a bunch of times in a row. If I only run the loop 10 times, it's fine, but 100 times, the error gets thrown.

Here's my code:

```
var request = require('request');

for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    request({
        url:'http://www.govtrack.us/api/v2/vote',
        qs:{
            related_bill : 292931
        }
    }, function(err, res, body){
        //console.log(res);
        console.log(err);
        //console.log(body);
    });
}
```

Here's the error:

```
node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at Socket.EventEmitter.addListener (events.js:160:15)
    at Socket.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:689:33)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.once (events.js:179:8)
    at Request.onResponse (/Users/Josh/Node/Dev/node_modules/request/request.js:625:25)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:175:14)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1689:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:120:23)
    at Socket.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1584:20)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:525:27)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in `request`, here is a discussion: https://github.com/mikeal/request/pull/623